# Accessing Skydrive services without a browser [XNA Game]

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, onedrive

We have a game that works on XNA on Windows Phone 7.1 and 8.
We want to add Cloud saving and loading of savegames like can be found on many different apps on android.
After i spent two weeks migrating my game from pure "XNA" to "XNA and XAML" i noticed a performance drop of almost 50%, so i decided that i need a different approach that didn't require a webbrowser control.

I was thinking of using REST calls via HTTPWebRequest like explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446517.aspx

Is this my only choice and or is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Making REST calls is the only sane way to do it.  However, use Portable HttpClient.

Comment: I will keep portableHttpClient in mind, thanks!

Comment: There is also an official Skydrive SDK for Windows Phone. It's probably easier than handling OAuth manually.

Comment: Thanks KooKiz, but I'm aware of it. The issue with the official sdk is that it only works on a xaml enabled project, not on a pure xna project. I worked two weeks to port my game to xaml but the underlying xaml causes a 50% drop in performances, wich is not acceptable by any means.